# How to get the current page number in displayTag pagination

Tags: struts2, pagination, displaytag

I would like to get the selected page number(in pagination) in my action class.I am using struts2 and displayTag pagination . Please help me to solve this problem. My display tag looks like

```
<display:table  name="searchList" class="mycolor"  id="row" sort="external" partialList="true" size="100" pagesize="25" requestURI="search-history-search" >
```

Please help me.... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected Page number will be passed as a request parameter 'page' to your Action class. Get the Request Parameter from HttpRequest for the selected page number.

Comment: hi ^_^ how did you get the page number from HttpRequest? please share ^_^ ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getParameter(new ParamEncoder("serviceRequestList")
       .encodeParameterName(TableTagParameters.PARAMETER_PAGE));
```

`serviceRequestList` is the id of display tag table.